# Canada visa (applying from US): Address to use for Package Transmission Fee made to "VFS Services (USA) Inc."

Tags: visas, canada, fees-and-charges

For a US resident, once their Canada visa application is approved, they need to send their passport to one of the Visa Application Centers in the US. Along with the passport, the applicant needs to send a money order or cashier check for the Package Transmission Fee. According to the [instructions](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/usa/en/can/passport-submission#) on the website of TT Services (a contractor for the government of Canada), the payee should be "VFS Services (USA) Inc." A USPS money order also needs an address for the payee. Which address should the applicant use for VFS Services (USA) Inc. on the money order?

Comment: What's the address of the Visa Application Center you are sending the application to?

Comment: @DJClayworth I am sending it to the New York Visa Application Center (VAC), with the address "VFS Global New York, Canada Visa Application Centre, 128E 32nd Street, 3rd Floor, New York, NY 10016, USA". I also thought if "VFS Services (USA) Inc." share the same address as the VAC, but there is not indication of it in the instructions. Also, just logically, "VFS Services (USA) Inc." as a company should be located at a specific address that cannot change as an applicant changes the VAC they send their passport to...?

Comment: ""VFS Services (USA) Inc." as a company should be located at a specific address that cannot change": a large company doesn't necessarily have a single address.  They can have thousands of offices; each office has a different address.  Use the address of the office to which you are mailing the money order.

Comment: @phoog That makes sense. So should the payee address of VFS Services (USA) Inc. be the same as the VAC the applicant sends their passport to?

Comment: @tvk it probably doesn't matter much.  The identity of the payee is clear and the money order will be paid to their bank account accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called TT Services at 888-296-4511. (VFS Global operates The Canada Visa Application Centre on behalf of TT Services, the exclusive service provider for the Government of Canada.) The agent said that one can just leave the payee address blank on the money order.

Answer (score 4):

[The page you cite in your question](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/usa/en/can/passport-submission#) contains two rows of tabs. In the second tab row, the second tab ("[Passport Submission](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/usa/en/can/passport-submission)") contains the addresses:

> Once you receive notification from the Government of Canada requesting your passport, please send your documents via any courier company of your choosing to the VAC.
> Please address the package containing your passport to the following address when submitting by courier:
>
> **Los Angeles VAC**
>
> VFS Global Los Angeles
> Canada Visa Application Centre
> 8530 Wilshire Blvd. Suite 450
> Beverly Hills CA, 90211, USA
> New York VAC
>
> **New York VAC**
>
> VFS Global New York
> Canada Visa Application Centre
> 128E 32nd Street, 3rd Floor,
> New York, NY 10016, USA

Comment: I see the addresses of the VACs. Should the payee address of VFS Services (USA) Inc. be the same as whichever VAC the applicant sends their passport to?

Comment: The address of the payee would be _the address where the payee is_, that is, where you're sending it. Why would you use a different address?

Comment: It is just unclear to me where the payee is: I am sending my passport to VFS Global New York but the payee is VFS Services (USA) Inc. While the two agencies appear to be related, they are not necessarily located at the same address. It is possible that the payee is a separate financial arm that processes payments centrally, located at a different address.

Comment: @tvk Yes, that's possible. But you're overthinking this. If there's a central processing office behind the scenes, they don't disclose its whereabouts and they don't direct you to say the "payee address" is anywhere different than where you send it.